# Is there a way to access elements of a loaded page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the jQuery function `.load()` to load a page.

Is there a way to access html elements contained in the loaded page from the source page once finished loading?

The only way I found is to add parameters in the URI. Is there an better way?

**EDIT**

Here is the code I'm trying to write:

```
$('.openInDialog').click(function(e) {
    var modal = $('#modal');
    var modalContent = $('#modal .modal-content');

    modal
        .on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            modalContent.load(e.currentTarget.href, function(){
                alert($(this).find('#firstName').html());
            });
        })
        .modal();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The line `alert($(this).find('#firstName').html());` returns an empty string.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: _Is there a way to access html elements contained in the loaded page from the source page once finished loading?_ Yes.

Comment: _"add parameters in the URI..."_ - As in using the [loading page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) functionality? If this doesn't match your use case could you post in more detail exactly what you're needing to do?

Comment: After you call `.load()`, the loaded page is part of the source page's DOM. You access the elements the same way you access anything else.

Comment: All jQuery ajax methods have a callback, the content can be accessed inside the callback, when it's gotten and available

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you load page contents into a div with an id `page`:

```
$("#page").load("page.html");
```

In that case, you need to add a callback function and access the added elements with the help of `children()`:

```
$("#page").load("page.html", function() {
    $(this).children(); // Selects everything that was loaded
    $(this).children("span"); // Selects all loaded span elements
    $(this).children(".test"); // Selects all loaded elements with test class
});
```